# search and filter with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, search, knockout.js

What i want to do is create a search that would find items that match search criteria. For example if i want to search for a book called "a song of ice and fire"... a "a song" needs to be enough to find a filter results. **Search critieria is search by book title**

I'm getting my data from sql server database, via mvc controller and on client-site with this method, which actually works fine and displays data in table (as i'm only testing if i get this data).

**PS:** The important thing here is that final result is, that i am not displaying all the books in any grid/table and doing search/filtering on that table, it all should be inbeded in search and only found by search method.

**update1**

```
self.search = function (value) {
            self.AllBooks.removeAll();
            for (var x in self.AllBooks) {
                if (self.AllBooks[x].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    self.AllBooks.push(self.AllBooks[x]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using knockout, I'll show you a more "reactive", typical knockout way of tackling this feature.

Your viewmodel should have one, private *data source* property. In your case, a list of *all* books that never changes. *You should **not** clear this list*.

Then, in another property, you store a `computed` list of data (books). This list takes a `filter` function and applies it to the full data source.

The filter method relies on your search query (`value`, in your search method). Let's make it `observable` so we know when to trigger updates!

Here's an example with *minimal changes to your original code* putting it all together:

```js
function Book(data) {
  var self = this;
  for (var key in data) {
    this[key] = ko.observable(data[key] == null ? "" : data[key]);
  }
}

function BookViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.title = ko.observable();
  
  self.searchQuery = ko.observable("");
  
  // The data source
  self.ListOfBooks = ko.observableArray([]);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    self.ListOfBooks.push(new BookList(data[i]));
  };
  
  // The filtered list
  self.searchResults = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var query = self.searchQuery().trim().toLowerCase();
    
    if (!query) return [];
    
    return self.ListOfBooks().filter(function(list) {
      // The actual search method, easily moved or replaced
      // by some other logic
      var book = list.Book();
      
      return Object.keys(book).some(function(k) {
        return ko.unwrap(book[k]).toLowerCase().includes(query);
      })
    });
  });
}

function BookList(data) {
  var self = this;
  for (var key in data) {
    if (key != "Book")
      this[key] = ko.observable(data[key] == null ? "" : data[key]);
  }
  self.Book = ko.observable(data.Book)

}

var _allBooks = [ 
  { Book: { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", author: "Harper Lee" }},
  { Book: { title: "Animal Farm", author: "George Orwell" }},
  { Book: { title: "The Lord of the Rings", author: "J.R.R. Tolkien" }}
];
ko.applyBindings(new BookViewModel(_allBooks == null ? new Array() : _allBooks));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<input type="search" data-bind="textInput: searchQuery">
<ul data-bind="foreach: searchResults">
  <li data-bind="with: Book">
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>, by <span data-bind="text: author"></span>
  </li>
</ul>




<div data-bind="visible: !searchQuery()" style="opacity: .5">
  <p>(Try searching for these books:)</p>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: ListOfBooks">
  <li data-bind="with: Book">
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>, by <span data-bind="text: author"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

A second example, in which I refactored some other parts as well, move some stuff around and use some more modern js features:

```js
function Book(data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    this[key] = ko.observable(data[key] == null ? "" : data[key]);
  }
  
  this.searchString = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    Object
      .keys(data)
      .map(k => this[k])
      .map(ko.unwrap)
      .join("||")
      .toLowerCase()
  );
};

Book.fromData = data => new Book(data);
Book.matchesQuery = query => book => book.matchesQuery(query);

Book.prototype.matchesQuery = function(query) {
  return this.searchString().includes(query.trim().toLowerCase());
};

function BookViewModel(data) {
  this.searchQuery = ko.observable("");
  
  // The data source
  this.allBooks = ko.observableArray(data.map(Book.fromData));
  
  // The filtered list
  this.searchResults = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    return this.searchQuery()
      ? this.allBooks().filter(Book.matchesQuery(this.searchQuery()))
      : [];
  });
}

var _allBooks = [ 
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", author: "Harper Lee" },
  { title: "Animal Farm", author: "George Orwell" },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings", author: "J.R.R. Tolkien" }
];

ko.applyBindings(new BookViewModel(_allBooks));
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;}

.searchwidget > input {
  width: 50%;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.searchwidget ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  
}

.searchwidget li {
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  list-style: none;
  
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-width: 0;
  background: #efefef;
  opacity: .95;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchwidget li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #dfdfdf;
}

.searchwidget > li:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="searchwidget">
  <input type="search" data-bind="textInput: searchQuery">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: searchResults">
    <li>
      <span data-bind="text: title"></span>, by <span data-bind="text: author"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>



<div data-bind="visible: !searchQuery()" style="opacity: .5">
  <p>(Try searching for these books:)</p>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: allBooks">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>, by <span data-bind="text: author"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is great! one last quesiton. is there a way to put "all this" inside search bar...meaning that if i type "mocking bird", suggestion will show inside search bar raher than on unordered list?

Comment: I'd recommend using css to style the list to look like it's part of the search bar. If you're targeting only modern browsers, you could also have a look at the [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) spec, which offers similar features. It might also be worth to google for ready made knockout auto-complete plugins.

Comment: I edited the second example to make it feel more like an auto complete feature

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for! now i need to go through code and learn what id does step by step. thank you!

Comment: If you have any questions concerning specific bits of code, feel free to ask! Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

In the search function you are iterating over "ListOfBooks"array and adding the element matching to search criteria to same array ListOfBooks. This duplicates the elements which matches the criteria.

```js
var ListOfBooks = ["JavaBook", "C#Book", "JavaScriptBook", "HTMLBook"];
var value = "Java";
for (var x in ListOfBooks) {
  if (ListOfBooks[x].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    ListOfBooks.push(ListOfBooks[x]);
  }
}
console.log(ListOfBooks);
```

If you want to get results in separate array you can do:

```js
var ListOfBooks = ["JavaBook", "C#Book", "JavaScriptBook", "HTMLBook"];
var value = "Java";
var SearchResults = [];
for (var x in ListOfBooks) {
  if (ListOfBooks[x].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    SearchResults.push(ListOfBooks[x]);
  }
}
console.log(SearchResults);
```

Or if you want to retain all the elements matching the criteria you use splice method:

```js
var ListOfBooks = ["JavaBook", "C#Book", "JavaScriptBook", "HTMLBook"];
var value = "Java";
for (var x in ListOfBooks) {
  if (ListOfBooks[x].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
    ListOfBooks.splice(x, 1);
  }
}
console.log(ListOfBooks);
```

Comment: ok yeh i understand. wouldn't something like .removeAll() fix the problem? somethings like this: 
see update

Comment: This is not a best code practice to handle.. Why dont you look at underscore js   http://underscorejs.org/ `filter` function

Answer (score -1):

Using [Underscore JS](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) it is more clean and efficient,

```
var _=require("underscore");
var ListOfBooks = ["JavaBook", "C#Book", "JavaScriptBook", "HTMLBook"];
var searchBook="Java";
var filteredBooks = _.filter(ListOfBooks, function(books) {
    return books.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBook.toLowerCase() )>= 0;
});
console.log("filteredBooks " +JSON.stringify(filteredBooks));
```

Comment: as much as i appreciate your help, the question is about knockout.js and not underscore.js. i will consider yours in the future, but right now i'm trying to learn knockout.js

Comment: yeh, i know..but i really want to solve this with knockout, since other stuff is dealt with knockout too